# Pass variables to handlebars helper call

Tags: javascript, templating, handlebars.js

I'd like to pass template data to a "textfield" helper method I have defined, like this:

```
{{textfield label="{{label}}"
            id="account_{{attributes.id}}"
            name="account[{{attributes.name}}]"
            class="some-class"
            required="true"}}
```

(note the {{label}} and {{attributes.id}} references inside the {{textfield}} helper call)

Here is where I set up the template:

```
data = {
  "attributes": {
    "id": "name",
    "name": "name"
  },
  "label": "Name"
}
var templateHtml = 'markup here';
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
var formHtml = template(data);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yWn9/).

When I run this, I still see {{placeholders}} in the compiled markup.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the incorrect syntax to pass named parameters to your handlebars helper. What you want is something like this:

```
var data = {
  "attributes": {
    "name": "name"
  }
}
var templateHtml = '{{textfield name=attributes.name}}';
var template = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
var formHtml = template(data);
```

And an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yWn9/1/

Comment: Awesome!! Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks! So the keys are to 1) not include curly brackets around variable names within helper calls and 2) not include quotes around variable names.

Comment: Problem: What if I want to do this: id=account_attributes.id ? In this case, attributes.id does not seem to parse correctly, and according to the browser debugger, id is set to ''. Also, id=account[attributes.name] results in a syntax error. Any ideas as to a workaround?

Comment: That's a limitation of Handlebars as far as I know. You'd want to pre-assemble the `id` and pass it in with the data, or do that concatenation inside your helper.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that compiling the template twice works. Sucks from an efficiency standpoint, but it is what it is. If anyone has an alternative solution, please do post.

```
var data = { "something": "value", "id": "theId", "theClass": "class-here", "value": "the value" };
var markup = $('#test-template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(markup);
var compiled = template(data);
var template2 = Handlebars.compile(compiled);
var compiled2 = template2(data);
$('body').append(compiled2);
```

Here is a new [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE54P/) demonstrating the double compiling.

Comment: This works because the output of your first compile contains the placeholders from your helper.